# docker-compose web & app server composition forcing internal redirects

Tags: docker, routes, docker-compose

Learning docker and docker-compose, running into a stickler:

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  site:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile-site-dev"
    environment:
      - "HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect"
    volumes:
      - "./site/:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  app:
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile-server-dev"
    environment:
      - "HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect"
    volumes:
      - "./app/:/app/"
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
```

This instantiates an *nginx* web front-end and a *nodejs/express* back-end in *alpine* images.

The issue is when I trigger a 'get' to 'http://app:3000/service' from a webpage to the nodejs app container, it redirects to https (which fails because I don't have https set up on the container -- this is an adhoc internal test & http only is fine.)

Have tried with jquery $.get and axios.get -- same results.

I can exec into the 'site' container and ping 'app' just fine, and if I curl 'http://app:3000/testme' from the 'site' container (which just returns an "I'm Here!!!" response) it works just fine.

But something is forcing the 307 when I execute it from a page.

I'm not seeing any redirects in the nginx configuration (which would only affect page accesses, anyway), and there is nothing in my nodejs app code to trigger a redirect.

Seems like something in docker is forcing the redirect.

Note in the docker-compose file I've set the environment "HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect" on both containers, which doesn't seem to have any effect.

Any insights appreciated.

### Adding:

Dockerfile-site-dev:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Dockerfile-app-dev:

```
FROM node:10.13-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn global add nodemon
CMD ["sh","-c", "yarn install && nodemon ./index.js"]
```

On the site side, the nginx config is vanilla from the alpine base image.

Here is the index.html that triggers requests to the app server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vote SSE Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          text-align:center;}
    #yes,#no,#message {font-size: 1.5em;}
    button {border-radius:0.5em;background-color:lightgray;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Will "Hello, World!" bring world peace?</h1>
  <div><button id="yes">Yes</button></div><br>
  <div><button id="no">No</button></div>
  <br/><br/>
  <div id="message"></div>
</body>
<script src="./jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="./axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function vote(yes) {
    console.log('voting: ' + (yes? 'yes' : 'no'));
    axios.get("http://app:3000/vote?yes=" + yes)
    .then(function(rsp) {
      $("#yes").hide();
      $("#no").hide();
      $("#message").text("Thank you for your vote!");
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Axios get error: ' + err);
    });
  }

  $("#yes").on("click", function(){
    vote(true);
  });

  $("#no").on("click", function() {
    vote(false);
  });
</script>
</html>
```

For the app side, here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "callbacks",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

And here is the index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const sse = require('./sse');

const app = express()

let connections = [],
    votes = {yes: 0, no: 0};

app.use(sse);

app.get('/vote', function(req, res) {
  console.log('server in vote...');
  let i;

  if (req.query.yes === 'true')
    votes.yes++;
  else
    votes.no++;

  for (i = 0; ix < connections.length; ++i) {
    connections[i].sseSend(votes);
  }

  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/stream', function(req, res) {
  res.sseSetup();
  res.sseSend(votes);
  connections.push(res);
});

app.get('/testme', function(req, res) {
  console.log('server: in testme');
  res.send("I'm here!!!\n");
})

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

SSE is ServerEvent, which is what I'm trying to test.

Otherwise, all pretty basic.

I do think docker is suspect, somehow, by virtue of the fact that I can curl the app from the site container no issues (or maybe that is why it's *not* suspect...)

Comment: It's not going to be in your docker-compose. You will need to post the docker files or app configs to see what's what.

Comment: Ok, I added some more information.  See if that helps.

Comment: Dev environment is latest docker on MacOS X Sierra, all updates.  The page rendition seems to be fine, so I don't see how it could be the browser (Chrome, latest.)

Comment: Took out the SSE parts and calls.  No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html runs on the browser (outside of docker).

The browser is not aware of any "app" host.

So in your html, replace:

```
    axios.get("http://app:3000/vote?yes=" + yes)
```

with

```
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/vote?yes=" + yes)
```

Comment: Well, duh.  I had it in my head the request it was being initiated from the site container...

Sometimes have trouble keeping all the actors straight...  Thx